# How to manipulate mapbox symbol icons - MapboxGL.js

Tags: layers, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I have my own Mapbox style that I build in MapBox Studio. Now I want to allow my user to move `poi_label` symbols. How could I do that? I am following this example [Create a draggable point](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-point/) and also I am aware of [Mapbox properties](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-symbol-icon-rotate). I have added my code below where I can access the layer, now how can I make this symbol draggable/movable?

```js
     map.on('load', function () {
      var layers = map.getStyle().layers;
      layers.forEach(function (layer) {
        if (layer.type && layer.type == "symbol"
          && layer["source-layer"] && layer["source-layer"] == "poi_label") {
          layer.draggable = true;// not working
          map.on('mouseenter', layer.id, function () {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'draggable';
          });
          map.on('mouseleave', layer.id, function () {
            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
          });          
        }
      });
```

In the [Create a draggable point](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-point/) example, the author is using manual `geojson` data. Is there any way to build this geojson programmatically based on the loaded part of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using [querySourceFeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#querysourcefeatures) to get the GeoJSON from there you can use the draggable point example you've linked to.

Comment: What do I need to pass in the `querySourceFeatures` to get the features in the map screen?

Comment: Check the API docs I linked to, after all that's all I would be doing...

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHarvey it helped